# How to override the math marker $ correctly?

Tags: math-mode

I would like the following sentence to appear in my document (literally):

**Our estimator of $\theta$ converges.**

I tried to do it like this:

**Our estimator of \$\backslash theta\$ converges.**

The result is that **$\theta$** is indeed printed like I want, but everything after that (i.e. the rest of the paragraph) becomes italicized and all spaces between words are deleted.

What is the right way to go about overriding the math marker $? What am I doing wrong?

I'm working on WinEdt to create an HTML document (LaTeX -> HTML), if that makes any difference. Thanks!

Comment: if the rest of the para was in math mode you must have a `$` somewhere that you have not quoted as `\$` please make a _complete_ small document that shows the problem. The standard command is `\textbackslash` not `\backslash`  oh that's  the answer:-)

Comment: Do you mean that you want to get the output yielded by `\verb|$\theta$|`?

Comment: @GustavoMezzetti that is exactly what I needed! Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Do not ignore errors! After an error the generated PDF isn't intended to be usable.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

Our estimator of \$\backslash theta\$ conver


\end{document}
```

produces

```
! Missing $ inserted.
<inserted text> 
                $
l.5 Our estimator of \$\backslash
                                  theta\$ conver
?
```

where the position of the line break shows that the problem is `\backslash` which is a math mode command.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

Our estimator of \$\textbackslash theta\$ conver


\end{document}
```

has no error message.